# Showing UIAlertView (With Option) on back to previous view in iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to Show UIAlertView asking "Save" or "Don't save" on Back Click to previous view in navigation based iPhone Application.

Should I write it on, ViewWillDisappear of current View ? Is that proper ?
Or any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of blindly showing the `UIAlertView` for saving. I suggest have a `BOOL` flag in your code by default `FALSE` which means data not saved. If the user saved his data then make this flag `TRUE`. So when the view is about to `popViewController` then check this flag. If `FALSE` only then show the `alertView`.

If I am not wrong, generally when you are about to `pop` a viewController, you link it to some button right? in that `IBAction` method put this check.

Comment: There is no specified method for Back button on UINavigationController. So I guess I must write the code in ViewWillDisappear:

Comment: Doesn't work putting it in ViewWillDisappear:, any other way? Which method gets called when We tap on "Back" to Previous View in navigation based app.

Comment: yes it should work when you put in `viewWillDisappear`. Check this out - http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/